# Are weapon upgrades permanent or just for that particular instance of a gun?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

In Bioshock Infinite, you can only hold two weapons at once. If I upgrade say, my pistol and later drop my pistol for a shotgun, do I have to re-buy the weapon upgrade if I later pick up a *different* pistol?

If this is the case, then is there any way to tell which pistol lying on the floor is the one with the upgrade?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, upgrades unlocked will not apply to any "instance" of that gun.

So yes, you can drop your pistol and pick a new one later and you will still have all the upgrades you unlocked.

Comment: And inversely: no matter which pistol you pick up, none will have any upgrades unless you've upgraded yours first.

Comment: Right, I played a lot of System Shock 2, where each weapon is distinct in its maintenance/upgrade state so I thought the same might apply here, but this is not the case! :) I assume 1999 mode doesn't 'fix' this?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Are you talking about the Maintenance, Repair and the Skill stats for each weapon type? (i also played a lot of System Shock 2) If thats the case, its probably because SS2 had weapon maintenance where they could break after using. Bioshock doesn't have that. And your weapon skill is global on top of that...

Comment: I mean the 50% durability, upgrade level 1 pistol you had in your inventory stays that way when you drop it, and the next pistol you pick up might be a 20% durability upgrade level 0 pistol. If you used an Epstein device to upgrade a weapon, it would only upgrade that one weapon, while if you increased your upgrade skill you could upgrade any weapon you found with that skill req, but it would take you time and money. Bioshock Infinite is really just upgrading weapon skills, not the weapons themselves! (or, are you upgrading every weapon in the game?)

Comment: Gotcha, in SS2 it was more of a "weapon modifier"-thing. SS2 was more of an RPG with permament item instances, so the durability of weapons fits there, but Infinite is more of a shooter, so it doesn't fit here.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it like you're upgrading your *skill* with a particular firearm, rather than upgrading the firearm *itself*.

Any firearm you find and upgrade, upgrades *all* firearms of the same type. (I know that sounds physically flawed, but that's how it works).